# Setting up Zend Framework DB garbage collection in application.ini? (and bootstrap ?)

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm storing all my sessions into the database with this in the application.ini

```
/* Session */
resources.session.use_only_cookies = on
resources.session.gc_maxlifetime = 864000
resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 864000
resources.session.cookie_lifetime = 864000
resources.session.name= "sessionName"

resources.session.saveHandler.class = "Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable"

resources.session.saveHandler.options.name = "sessions"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primary = "id"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.modifiedColumn = "modified"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.dataColumn = "data"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.lifetimeColumn = "lifetime"
```

The expired session aren't being deleted in the database. What am I missing? Should there be something in the bootstrap? If anyone can help it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an expired session is deleted from the database when the session is `read` or when `destroy` is called.

```
//from Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable
 public function read($id)
    {
        $return = '';

        $rows = call_user_func_array(array(&$this, 'find'), $this->_getPrimary($id));

        if (count($rows)) {
            if ($this->_getExpirationTime($row = $rows->current()) > time()) {
                $return = $row->{$this->_dataColumn};
            } else {
                $this->destroy($id);
            }
        }

        return $return;
    }


 public function destroy($id)
    {
        $return = false;

        if ($this->delete($this->_getPrimary($id, self::PRIMARY_TYPE_WHERECLAUSE))) {
            $return = true;
        }

        return $return;
    }
```

There may be other instances where the database record is removed but I haven't located them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Looking at this, it seems that it only destroys or restarts the session if I provide it the sessionid. How about if two weeks go by and the person never comes back? I don't have a sessionid to provide it. I've looked around and there is a gc_maxlifetime and gc_dividor and etc which uses a garbage collector to get rid of the outdated sessions. Am I misunderstanding the concept of automatic expiration from database table and have to call the functions to expire explicitly? perhaps with a cronjob?

Comment: If you think about it, there is no way for the save handler to know if a session has expired until it tries to access it in some way. After all the expiration data is kept in the database or the cookie. So really a maintenance operation like a cron job would be the most practical way to handle the cleaning of the database.